# Dangling else determinism

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, nondeterminism

The natural grammar for dangling "else" is ambiguous.
But there exists an unambiguous version of the grammar that links the "else" to last uncompleted "if" statement.
Is this version also deterministic?
Is this language deterministic?

Natural grammar (ambiguous):
$$
S \rightarrow if~expr~S | if~expr~S~else~S | cmd
$$

Unambiguous grammar:
$$\begin{align*}
S &\rightarrow U~|~F\\
U &\rightarrow if~expr~S~|~if~expr~F~else~U\\
F &\rightarrow if~expr~F~else~F~|~cmd
\end{align*}$$

Comment: This is a good question, because not all unambiguous context-free languages are deterministic, and it may not be immediately clear if this is the case here. However, there's a simple test: A context-free language is deterministic if and only if it has a grammar which is $LR(k)$ for some $k$. So why not see if your favourite unambiguous grammar is $LR$?

Comment: Where do these grammars come from? Note how the issue is easily fixed by using some kind of parenthesisation.

Comment: @Raphael This grammars are in every other formal languages course, that tries to explain ambiguity. Parenthesisation would change generated language. Point is if this language is deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed by [@Pseudonym](https://cs.stackexchange.com/users/6553/pseudonym) a context-free language is deterministic if and only if it has a grammar such that is $LR(k)$, for some $k$.
Let's take $k = 1$, the grammar is $LR(1)$ (and $LALR(1)$) so it is deterministic.